# Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to insert data to a database

But after pressing the button it show me thos error messege

Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.

I need help

I dont know what to do anymore. Thanks!!

```
private void InsertNewRecord()
            {
                SqlCommand cmdInsert = new SqlCommand();
                cmdInsert.Connection = cn;
                cmdInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customers (" +
                    " LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, ContactNumber, EmailAddress, BirthDate, CompanyName, Address, BillingAddress, CustomerStatus, CustPicture" +
                    ") VALUES (" +
                    " @LastName, @FirstName, @MiddleName, @ContactNumber, @EmailAddress, @BirthDate, @CompanyName, @Address, @BillingAddress, @CustomerStatus, @CustPicture" +
                    ") ";
                cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtLastName.Text;
                cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtFirstName.Text;
                cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@MiddleName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtMiddleName.Text;
                cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@ContactNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtContactNumber.Text;
                cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@EmailAddress", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtEmailAddress.Text;
                cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@BirthDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dtpBirthdate.Value;
                cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtCompanyName.Text;
                cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtAddress.Text;
                cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@BillingAddress", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtBillingAddress.Text;
                cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@CustomerStatus", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = cboCustomerStatus.Text;


                Image bmp;
                System.IO.MemoryStream ms;

                if (PicImage.Image == null)
                {
                    bmp = Bitmap.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + @"\Anonymous.jpg"); //read the default picture
                    ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                    bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp); //put it in the memory stream
                    cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@CustPicture", SqlDbType.Image).Value = ms.GetBuffer(); //add it as the value of custpictureparameter.
                }
                else
                {
                    bmp = Bitmap.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                    ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                    bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@CustPicture", SqlDbType.Image).Value = ms.GetBuffer();
                }
                cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully added row to Customers table!");

            } //end of InsertNewRecord()
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Even without stepping through your code, which would have indicated where the error is I can almost guarantee its on this line:

```
cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@ContactNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtContactNumber.Text;
```

You're saying the parameter is an integer and you're passing a string. You need to convert the value of `txtContactNumber.Text` to an integer.

Try `int.Parse` or preferably `int.TryParse`.

Comment: Incorrect. Conversion is automatically made if possible (i.e. the field can be converted to an int).

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the ContactNumber to an integer.

```
int contactNumber;
Int32.TryParse(ContactNumber.Text, out contactNumber);
```

Then add:

```
cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@ContactNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = contactNumber;
```

Comment: You hide conversion errors. At least mention that in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are incorrect. The parameter is automatically converted if the value is correctly formatted.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.sqlvalue.aspx):

> If the application specifies the database type, the bound value is converted to that type when the provider sends the data to the server. The provider tries to convert any type of value if it supports the IConvertible interface. Conversion errors may result if the specified type is not compatible with the value.

So make sure that there are no white spaces in the text box:

```
cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@ContactNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtContactNumber.Text.Trim();
```